# How can I get brownies to bake evenly?

Tags: baking, brownies

I can never get the middle of my brownies "done" without overbaking the outsides. The middle is tasty, but gooey.   What is the secret?

Answer (score 4):

### Oven Temperature

Most ovens keep inaccurate temperatures with respect to your setting. You may be setting it to 350, but it could be baking at 375. I would suggest investing in an oven thermometer. I've seen these for a dollar--well worth the investment.

### Baking Vessel

I was surprised to find this out, but the pan color actually affects heat conduction. If you use a non-stick tin, for example, your brownies are more likely to burn. I've seen some people use silicone brownie pans to minimize this kind of uneven cooking.

Comment: Very true. My oven here really guarantees a minimum of 350 when set at 350 (and varies between 350 and 450). All ovens have this variability as they heat and cool, though most are not such a wide range. Also, further to Ray's suggestion above, it is often worth having a good mulitmeter around, and good ones tend to come with a thermistor component. Generally, a thermistor will be more accurate and sensitive than an oven thermometer.

Comment: You can always invest in a convection oven. The fan tends to even out the temperature a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is the center of the pan rather than the vertical center of the brownies, you could use

[image: edge brownie pan]

["The Edge Brownie Pan"](http://www.bakersedge.com/).

Comment: Or, rather than getting a tool that doesn't have a whole lot of uses (although, I think I remember someone telling me that some brands of lasagne noodle fit perfectly in there), you could use a muffin pan to get a similar effect, if you don't mind round brownies.

Comment: But the center is the best part! =)

Answer (score 1):

You can put your brownie pan in a larger pan...then fill that larger pan with water about 3/4. cook as normal but the water in the larger pan with help diffuse all the direct heat to the sides.

Comment: AKA a [bain-marie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bain-marie).