# Can a water bath be used to bake brownies?

Tags: baking, water, brownies

I've never used a water bath when baking, but I know that people use it for baking cheese cakes (i.e., placing the cheese-cake form in a container with water), so I was wondering if the same concept could be used for brownies.

Whenever I bake brownies, all the edges become a bit too hard from overcooking. This is not a huge problem because it's only about a centimetre from the edge, and I just cut it off, but I was wondering if a water bath could help.

My main concern is whether the water evaporating would make the environment in the oven too humid and interfere with the batter. I would think the same thing about cheese cakes, but the fact that many people are doing that means it's OK in that case.

**Edit for clarification**: the rest of the brownie is cooked just right, so I'm less keen to change other variables like temperature and time. I've also started wondering about this because I'm aware of the ability of water to distribute and soften the effect of heat. For example, if I try to defrost meat in the microwave, it will start cooking on the outside before it defrosts in the centre; but if I microwave it in a bowl of water, it defrosts evenly.

Comment: You might want to simply ask how to avoid the edges getting too hard. There might be simpler methods than a water bath (like lowering your oven temperature). (See [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: As @jefromi suggests I would A) lower my oven temperature B) take my brownies out sooner (remember, brownies should be fudgy in the middle!) or C) invest in a light coloured pan that won't radiate as much heat onto the brownies' edges.

Comment: I think you should experiment and post the results here. @Jefromi you're totally right but the question is interesting on its own

Comment: @Jefromi You're right, but I'm curious as well about the specific method. After your comment, I thought of posting a separate question just on the hard edges, but a [similar question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14692/how-can-i-get-brownies-to-bake-evenly) already exists, and, interestingly, one of the suggestions is a water bath. In any case, I'll try it next time I'm baking brownies and let everyone know.

Comment: It is hard to hermetically seal the edges of a brownie pan, and condensation drips from the lid will do horrible things to a batter. I've tried. Microwave is probably a simpler option.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger, thanks. That's the type of info I'm looking for. Perhaps you should post it as an answer rather than a comment with some details. For example, I was just considering leaving the pan open; is there a reason to close/seal it? Re microwave, you mean I can bake in the microwave instead of the oven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cheese cakes water bath makes more sense cause you want to avoid burning of the batter by keeping the heat contact directly from the tray.

For brownies the contact of the hot plate is required, and that is how you get a little solid outer part.

When you try to water bath brownies, they would have more or less like cheese cake texture, I actually tried it.

Comment: Thanks, Giene! what do you mean exactly by "cheese-cake texture"? Is it soft/smooth vs crunchy? And does that affect the whole cake, or just the parts touching the tin or the top? The goal is to prevent the sides from getting too hard, but preserving the texture in the centre and on the top crust.

Comment: Hi Ratler, Cheese cake texture is from the inside prospective. Outside you dont want to be like a cracker hardness for brownies so water bath helps in giving softer texture outside.